# Unable to connect to remote SQL Server Instance from C# Application

Tags: c#, sql-server

We have a remote SQL Server instance on a VM that we can connect to successfully from SQL Server Management Studio on my local machine.

However I am having problems connecting to this database from a C# application. My connection string is as follows:

```
string ConnectionString = "server=METRODEMO\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Logger;Trusted_Connection=True;";
```

I have also checked and the properties on the remote SQL Server are as follows:

```
SQL Native Client 11.0 Configuration (32 bit)-->Client Protocols    
  Shared Memory - Enabled   
  TCP/IP        - Enabled   
  Named Pipes   - Enabled
```

In SQL Server Network Configuration -- Protocols for SQL Server Express, the properties for IP addresses have TCP Port set to 1433 in the IPAll section.

However when I try to connect, I get the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlExceptionHResult=0x80131904
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
> The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
> (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you verified the C# is actually using that connection string?

Comment: [Connectivity trouble shooter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: And have you "verified that the instance name is correct" or for that matter the machine name? Is there any firewalling between this machine and the client machine? Can you `ping` it from the client machine?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Trusted_Connection=yes` instead of `true`.  Or use `Integrated Security=SSPI` instead of `Trusted_Connection`

https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-11-0-oledb-provider/

So:

```
string ConnectionString = "server=METRODEMO\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Logger;Trusted_Connection=yes;";
```

Or:

```
string ConnectionString = "server=METRODEMO\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Logger;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
```

Comment: Highly unlikely to be the issue, because it's not even finding the server